# Transit via at CDG airport for Cuban citizens

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, france, cuban-citizens

Do I need a transit visa for a cuban in transit with a stopover of couple of hours without leaving transit area enroute Havana to London?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a UK visa you can transit without a visa according to Timatic (the database used by airlines):

> Transiting without a visa is possible for:
>
> Nationals of Cuba with a normal passport transiting through Paris (CDG), arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight within 24 hours to a third country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must:
>
> - have a visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania, USA or United Kingdom, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for their next destination.

**Note:** Neither Cuba or UK is a Schengen Member State so this guidance applies.

Comment: Sincere thx that's very helpful in buying a ticket

Comment: @SanjeevJuneja no problem, if my answer helped please accept it by pressing the tick on the left. Thanks